# How to use carrierwave without a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, afnetworking-2

I am trying to save a png in my rails app using the below code

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(params[:image])
```

But it's throwing ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)

What am i doing wrong here?

I am posting it via an ios app using AFNetworking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick excerpt from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075491/2803062) adapted to your question:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
File.open(params[:image]) do |file|
  something = uploader.store!(file)
end
uploader.retrieve_from_store!(self.file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks.. But i ended up using carrierwave-ios gem. That works like a charm. Will test this out sometime.

Answer (score 0):

If your `params[:image]` is an instance of either a `Tempfile` or a `StringIO`, you should call the method `read` on this instance.

Your code should be

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
image = params[:image]
uploader.store!(image.read)
```

Comment: It is the post parameter that i am passing.. I tried your code.. It's throwing "undefined method 'read'" error